# Pasting code from Mathcha into TikzEdt ruins marker alignments

Tags: tikz-pgf, editors, mathcha

I would like to migrate my Tikz code into [TikzEdt](http://www.tikzedt.org/index.html) from [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io), in order to manipulate the code as well as the graphics at times. I downloaded it and pasted a small code for a drawing. There were no markers (the `x` signs) on the canvas.

I realised the markers were not affected by the `x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt` options Mathcha adds to the `tikzpicture` environment, while the drawing itself was, so I removed these hoping to realign the once-out-of-screen markers with their corresponding shapes. I got both drawings and markers visible inside the canvas - but they were still not aligned.

When I drew a new rectangle I also got its markers misaligned with its shape and as a side-effect this addition also shifted the previous drawings (the pasted ones) while leaving their markers untouched. Opening a new file and drawing a rectangle did not reproduce this meaning it must have come from the pasting itself somehow. But after commenting out everything except the newly drawn rectangle the misalignment still happens.

The Preamble tab is showing an empty dynamic preamble.

What is that and how can that be fixed? (I would like to be able to use code generated by mathcha and inside TikzEdt)
Here is the current code and screenshot (try pasting it into TikzEdt and drawing a new rectangle if you don't see the misalignment of the original rectangle. On my computer just pasting this into a new instance is enough):

```
% \end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw  (-2.5,1.5) rectangle (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: screenshot: TikzEdt misaligns shape and markers]

Comment: The above code you provided results in a rectangle, but without any markers attached. Where do they come from? I guess, you need to provide a bit more code for us to understand the situation.

Comment: It does come with markers when I paste it into a fresh TikzEdt, but they are properly aligned. I didn't think this would reproduce the problem - that's why I bothered explaining the steps that got to it to happen (pasting from Mathcha; adding the rectangle; and commenting out everything else). I added the commented-out code now and when I paste it all into a fresh instance of the program the misalignment occurs. (On the other hand, not every Mathcha code creates this misalignment, as I first suspected).

Comment: I do not use TikzEdt, and know nothing about how it extracts the coordinates from the code. Could you try to delete everything instead of commenting it out? Maybe paste matcha code in a text editor and only copy+paste the needed code to TikzEdt.

Comment: From: http://www.tikzedt.org/quicktour.html: "Note: Parsing Latex/Tikz code is not a simple task. Tikzedt can understand a couple of Tikz constructs, in particular coordinate transformation and polar coordinates. But, yes, it can be fooled.... see the documentation for more details. (In the worst case, you may always turn off the parser and use TikzEdt as a text editor with instant preview.)"

Comment: @hpekristiansen the commented-out part is what I actually need. I tried commenting-out different parts to zone-in on the culprit, but ended up commenting out EVERYTHING and still having the problem. I guess I do need to delete instead of commenting-out in order to uncover the cause, as TikzEdt still takes notice of the commented-out parts (which is weird).

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If not, could you update your question with the MINIMUM steps needed to reproduce the problem. Start everything from scratch and write as little code as possible to cause the problem.

Comment: No it hasn't been solved - personally I just didn't use TikzEdt and made my graphics in a different way. That's why I haven't continued investigating it before. Now I got the code to minimal and edited the question. It seems that the commented-out `\end{tikzpicture}` is being read and messes up the alignment (only when the commented-out command is full). It's a weird bug. It cannot be the only thing that triggers it, as originally I didn't have such a line commented-out. Further investigation is needed in order to understand this. For now I might avoid pasting Mathcha code there.

Comment: I've tried and I think it is a bug of TikzEdt. If you delete `%\end{tikzpicture}`, wait for compilation, all is fine, then if you paste again `%\end{tikzpicture}` seem that all remain fine.

Comment: @vipa of course it is a bug :) I just hoped I would understand it enough to be able to work around it and be able to paste my code from Mathcha and use the functionality of TikzEdt afterwards. But I gave up on this by now... I'm leaving this here so people will know of this bug.

Comment: A workaround could be that you have to delete the commented part, wait for compilation and paste again the commented part.

Comment: I sometimes use TikzEdt and it works very well if you have only one tikzpicture to work with.

Comment: As I wrote in the question and in the previous comment - the minimal working code is not the code I needed and have had the bug showing up originally. In the original code there is no line like `%\end{tikzpicture}` so I wouldn't have known how to try applying it there - as I hadn't zeroed-in on the culprit part of the code. But it's good to know - maybe it could be of use for others who get this bug happening to them and do know what part is causing it.